# Controlling an LED's intensity with a text file from an SD card

Tags: arduino, led, software, sd

I want to control the intensity of an [LED](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-emitting_diode) by reading a text file. Here is an example of a text file:

```
255,100,255,50,100,20,10,200,50,90,85,200,0,0,0,255
```

My equipment: [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno), microSD [shield](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoShields), power LED shield, and microSD card.

What I want is: during 60 seconds, my LED's light intensity is `i` and after that, the intensity is `i+1`, etc. In this example, that would be an intensity of 255, then one of 100, then 255, etc. I know how to read a text file and open a text file with the SD library, but I don't know how to parse my text file and get the good intensity at the time `t`. So I want something like this:

```
# Open and read the file from the SD card
# For t to the end of the file
      intensity = intensity at t
      analogWrite(led,intensity)
      delay(60000)
# For each time t, I want to have the intensity I on my screen
      Serial.println(intensity);
```

Next, I want to do that for two LEDs with two different arrays on the same text file.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Found on the Arduino Forums, showing how to take a CSV (comma separated value) file like yours, reading it into an array:

```
  File configFile = SD.open("CONFIG.TXT");
  if(configFile){
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
      config[i]=configFile.parseInt();
    configFile.close();
  }
```

Also the [Arduino SD library reference page](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/SD)
The SD library's File class is inherited from the [Stream Class](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Stream) and most if not all of it's functions apply to the SD File class, including ParseInt():

> parseInt() returns the first valid (long) integer number from the current position. Initial characters that are not integers (or the minus sign) are skipped. parseInt() is terminated by the first character that is not a digit.

To make an arbitrary file length, you would want to use a combination of the File class size() and available(), and fixed digit format. Instead of `255,4,30,255,0,` make sure every number you add is zero padded to 3 digits so you get `255,004,030,255,000,`. Then you could simply take the file.size(), divide by 4, and your arduino sketch will know how many numbers are in the file.

I'll leave the rest to you on how to figure it out. You don't have to read it into an array for example. And if you want to use it for two different leds, you could possibly just interspace your data, so that `255,240,000,010,100,255` would be for led1, led2, led1, led2, and so on.

Comment: I try to do your work but I have a problem with config : I declare it like an integer but it's not work. Do you know wich type of variable is it ?

Comment: In that example, it's an int array. It should work by initializing as `int config=0;` then on the line needed, using `config = configFile.parseInt();`. Each time you call "configFile.parseInt();" it will return the next valid int. @user22115

Answer (score 1):

To make it easier you might want to write raw data to the textfile (one byte a value). This has the drawback that it's not so easy to read in a text editor and should be edited with a hexedit tool (there's a nice plugin for Notepad++). In such a case, you can open the file and read the file bytewise where each byte is your new value.

If you really want to do it with readable text, you have to resort to using the standard C tools such as strtok and sscanf. I hope they are available with Arduino, maybe you'll have to add stdio.h. In this case, use strtok to split your string into tokens (split on every comma), then use sscanf to convert the textual representation to a numeric representation.

Comment: While not wrong, that's overly complicated. +1 to negate that downvote though.

Comment: `strtok()` is in `string.h`, but both functions are available in AVR Libc.